# Implicit conversion confusion between signed and unsigned when reading K&R book

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

I am learning the c language using the K&R book. In the second chapter book, the author talks about implicit conversion. There book says this:

> Conversion rules are more complicated when unsigned operands are involved. The problem is that 
>   comparisons between signed and unsigned values are machine-dependent, because they depend on the sizes of the various integer types. For example, suppose that int is 16 bits and long is 32 bits. Then -1L < 1U, because 1U, which is an unsigned int, is promoted to a signed long. But -1L > 
>   1UL because -1L is promoted to unsigned long and thus appears to be a large positive number.

I tried the code below in two different scenarios:

1. compiled on an x86 64bits platform and executed. Where `sizeof(-1L)` -> 8byte and `sizeof(1U)` -> 4 bytes
2. compiled on an x86 32bits platform and executed. Where `sizeof(-1L)` -> 4byte and `sizeof(1U)` -> 4 bytes

The code:

```
int main() {
 if(-1L > 1U)
    printf("true");
    else
    printf("false");
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

1. x86 64bits: `false`
2. x86 32bits: `true`

so I'm getting two different OP in each case.

As author says, for 2 different data sizes one being 16 and the other 32, it holds good in my x86-64 case.

But im not able to understand why in the second case for 32 bits, I'm getting `true`. 
As author says `unsigned int` is promoted to `signed long int`, if this is true then both
should be 4 bytes wide, then why is it printing `true` instead of `false`? As now both should be `signed long`.

As the author says it is machine dependent, then both `long` and `int` should have same byte size, so how the implicit conversion is happening here?

My understanding is that `-1` is stored as two's complement *i.e* `0xFFFFFFFF` > `0x1` so in the second case it should be `true`.

But this explanation contradicts the 1st case.

Please correct me if what I think is wrong, as I am new to implicit conversion.

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Shouldn't `-1L > 1LU` evaluate to true in both case?

Comment: sorry typo its not 1LU its 1U

Answer (score 4):

lets explain the rank system first

```
6.3.1 Arithmetic operand(c99 standard)

A) The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer
type with less precision(more bytes higher precision higher rank)

B) The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be
greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short int, which 
shall be greater than the rank of signed char.

C) The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed 
integer type, if any.
(in other words if your system unsigned int is 32bits and your int is 32bits then the 
ranks of these are the same.)
```

the above explains the rank.

now coming to arithmetic conversions.

```
6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions (c99 standard)

1)If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.

2)Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer 
 types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is converted to the
 type of the operand with greater rank.(similar to 1)

3)Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to  
  the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is
  converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

4)Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the 
  values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with 
  unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type

5)Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
  type of the operand with signed integer type.
```

2) compiled on an x86 32bits platform and executed. Where sizeof(-1L) -> 4byte and sizeof(1U) -> 4 bytes

in your case look at statement 3 & C. the unsigned value(4bytes) has rank equal to the signed value(4btyes) therefore the singed value is converted to an unsigned value, when this happens the, the sign bit makes this look like a extremely large value. -1L > 1U therefore is true

1) compiled on an x86 64bits platform and executed. Where sizeof(-1L) -> 8byte and sizeof(1U) -> 4 bytes

in this case, the unsigned value rank is less than the rank of the singed value. look at 4).
the signed integer(8bytes) can represent any 4byte unsigned value. therefore the unsigned 4byte value is converted to a signed value.(this will preserve the sign bit, sign bit is 0)

therefore -1L > 1U is false

Answer (score 2):

For binary arithmetic and relational operators:

If either operand has type long double, the other operand is converted to long double. Otherwise, if either operand has type double, the other operand is converted to double. Otherwise, if either operand has type float, the other operand is converted to float. Otherwise the integral promotions are performed on both operands.

(Integral promotion: A char, a short int, or an int bit-field, or their signed or unsigned varieties, or an enumeration type, may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used. If an int can represent all the values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise it is converted to an unsigned int.)

Then if either operand has type unsigned long int, the other operand is converted to unsigned long int. Otherwise, if one operand has type long int and the other has type unsigned int, if a long int can represent all values of an unsigned int the operand of type unsigned int is converted to long int; **if a long int cannot represent all the values of an unsigned int, both operands are converted to unsigned long int.** Otherwise, if either operand has type long int, the other operand is converted to long int. Otherwise, if either operand has type unsigned int, the other operand is converted to unsigned int. Otherwise, both operands have type int.

The sentence in bold explains your second case, where long int has the same width as unsigned int thus cannot hold all values of unsigned int.

(The above description lacks the type `unsigned long long int` and `long long it`, but the rules are basically the same.)

Answer (score 2):

> But im not able to understand why in second case in 32 bit its OP-->true. As author says unsigned int is promoted to signed long int if so then both are 4 byte wide, why its printing true instead of false.? since now both are signed long.

The auther says, that if `int` and `long` have *different* size, then `unsigned int` is promoted to `signed long`.

If `int` and `long` have the same size, then `long` is too small to hold all values of `unsigned int` and therefore both are converted to `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 0):

As all who answered above are correct, Just to add more clarity and my understanding writing here to get more clarity.

-->`if one operand has type long int and the other has type unsigned int,`

-->`if a long int can represent all values of an unsigned int the operand of type unsigned int is converted to long int;`

-->`if a long int cannot represent all the values of an unsigned int, both operands are converted to unsigned long int.`

So from above `one operand has type long int` i.e `-1L` and `the other has type unsigned int` i.e `1U`

suppose sizeof -1L is --->`8byte`  and sizeof 1U is `4 byte`

`0X0000-0XFFFFF values can be represented using in long int whose sizeof is 8 byte`

so in this case `long int can represent all values of an unsigned int` i.e  using 8byte ---> it can represent all the values `unsigned int 1U`.

so----> here `operand of type unsigned int is converted to long int` ---> `-1L > 1U --> is false`

coming 2nd case

`if a long int cannot represent all the values of an unsigned int`

i.e sizeof `-1L -->4byte` and sizeof `1U -->4byte`

here long int cannot represent all the values i.e using 4 bytes--> it `cannot represent` all the values of unsigned int 1U. so both operands are `converted to unsigned long int`

-1L appears to  large value since its unsigned now when compared to 1U.

`i.e---->0xFFFFFFFF > 0x1 ---> its true`